# Setting title for code line in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I use RStudio.

The default title of each line is "Untitled" as you can see in the first picture.
[image]

Today, I found that the title of each line can be modified. As we can see, the title in the second picture is different.
[image]

But I don't know how to set the title. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections

Comment: ...save the file and magic happens

Comment: @RichardScriven this is not the filename, it is the section name. It shows the section for not saved files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is either the section name (if it has an orange `#`) or the function name (if it has a blue `f`).

You can define sections with

```
## Section name ----
```

or

```
## Section name ====
```

or

```
## Section name ####
```

See the documentation [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections).

Comment: Thank you,alko989! This is the answer I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can define sections depending on the numbers of hashes at the beginning of the section header. The trailing sign (in my example it is -) and the number of trailing signs you put doesn't matter.

```
# section header Level 1 -----
## section header Level 2 -----
### section header Level 3 -----
```